# Not sure about the AMD Zen 3 Architecture (functional units, issue time / latency of instructions)

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization, amd-processor

I am trying to find information regarding the integer & floating point  functional units for the processor zen 3 architecture by AMD.

As well as the issue time (minimum time between two operations) & latency of integer & floating point (single & double precision) addition & multiplication.

I was using this link for the [architecture](https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf). Which starts at page 241 for Zen 3 details.

And this link for the [instruction infos](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf). Which starts at page 113.

I have went through [uops.info](https://uops.info/table.html) to read up on more of the instruction latencies.

I have also read [hack.md](https://hackmd.io/@hiFbws9HS-uyBrkLZP8c_w/rJq31JtyY)

I am not 100% sure if the information I gathered is correctly. The processor I have in mind is a Ryzen 7 5700X, here is what I gathered:

===1===

4 Integer ALU FUs (multiply/divide only use 1 out of 4) & 2 branch units & 3 Address Generation units
(Can execute 6 integer instructions per clock cycle on average as long as they are all different types)

6 Floating Point FUs (Including 2 multiply/addition & 2 further addition), 2 Address Generation units

===2===

Issue/latency of IADD : L1  I1

Issue/latency of IMUL : L3  I3

Issue/latency of FADD : L3  or L6 (from uops, not sure where to get issue time)

Issue/latency of FMUL : L3  or L6 (from uops, not sure where to get issue time)

Unsure if the data I gathered for floating point is single or double precision

===3===

Multiply & Add fused has L4
Throughput of 2 FADD, 2 FMUL. Simple integer instruction has throughput 4

I think my information in point 1 is correct. However, I am unable to confirm the latency in part 2, I am also unable to find the issue time for these instructions. I would like some help in verifying the information I gathered and how/where I can find the data I need for part 2.

I have tried reading through both the PDFs (Zen 3 section) as well as uops.info to gather data but I am not confident if what I understand is correct and would like to request assistance in clearing up my misunderstandings.

Comment: *6 Floating Point FUs* - 6 ports, but different functional units can share the same port. 
 e.g. SIMD shuffles and bitwise booleans clearly need different hardware than FP math.  And 2 of those 6 ports are dedicated (1 each) to FP store-data and FP->int transfers, so really only 4 FP execution ports (2 having MUL/FMA units, 2 having ADD units, same as Zen 2, but no competition from FP stores anymore.) 
 https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_3#Key_changes_from_Zen_2 / https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2#Block_Diagram shows the 4 SIMD/FP pipes in Zen 2

Comment: @PeterCordes hello, thank you for the clarification, I was wondering where the missing two were, now I know.

Comment: What is Issue Time? It's something AMD-specific? uiCA only simulates Intel CPUs and has a fixed 5c delay between issue and dispatch of any instruction.

Comment: @MargaretBloom hello, I updated the post to include the meaning. I learnt of this term from a website that took from some book presumably. It was referring to it as "minimum time between two operations".

Comment: The minimum time (in cycles) between execution of *dependent* operations is called *latency*.  https://uops.info/ measures that for every instruction, or at least an upper bound for instructions where the input and output are in different domains.  (Like `movd xmm0, eax` or `vmovmskps eax, xmm0`, `ucomisd xmm0, xmm1`, or loads/stores.)  In Intel / x86 terminology, sending a uop to an execution port is "dispatch", while "issue" is alloc/rename and move a uop from the front-end to the ROB+scheduler.  Those two terms are swapped vs. many other computer-architecture texts.

Comment: BTW, `FADD` is legacy x87 (80-bit long double).  For scalar float or double, and SIMD, look at `addss` (scalar single) / `addsd` (scalar double), and `addpd` (packed double) / `vaddpd ymm` (256-bit vectors of 4 doubles).  Look at compiler output to see what instructions compilers actually use; [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: *(Can execute 6 integer instructions per clock cycle on average as long as they are all different types)* - I think the front-end is a bottleneck for that, unless that's changed since Zen 1; issue/rename can handle up to 5 instructions per clock, or up to 6 uops.  To get 6 uops through the front-end, at least one of the instructions has to be more than 1 uop.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to close this question. I think this is it for zen 3. Not exactly sure.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfp7U.png

Comment: `fadd` is an x87 instruction so it's confusing to use it for talking about other FP addition instructions if that's what you're doing in the 2nd section, about xmm/ymm.  The instructions that operate on xmm/ymm registers are `addss` / `addsd` and `vaddps/pd`.